# Foreign Key Relation Problem in Django Rest Framework API

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-serializer

**I have the following models:**

```
class Users(models.Model):
    user_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    home_page = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    user_email = models.EmailField(max_length=70, unique=True)
    user_password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class Posts(models.Model):
    post_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    uri = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    post_body = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
    post_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**and I have the following Serializers:**

```
class UsersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Users
        fields = ('user_id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'user_email', 'username',
                  'home_page', 'user_password', 'mobile_number', 'is_active')


class PostsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Posts
        fields = ('post_id', 'user_id', 'uri', 'location', 'title', 'summary', 'post_body', 'post_datetime', 'votes')
```

**This is my View Code:**

```
class ListCreatePostsView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Posts.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostsSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        a_Post = Posts.objects.create(
            user_id=request.data["user_id"],
            title=request.data["title"],
            location=request.data["location"],
            summary=request.data["summary"],
            post_body=request.data["post_body"],
            uri=request.data["uri"],
            votes=request.data["votes"]

        )
        return Response(
            data=PostsSerializer(a_Post).data,
            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
        )
```

I have an API running using Django Rest Framework. However, when I try to add a new Post to a specific `user_id`, i get the following error from the API view:

```
Cannot assign "'528c2d9e-da2e-4c3d-9a92-eafb98e5d06e'": "Posts.user_id" must be a "Users" instance.
```

Is it a problem with my Serializers implementation? `user_id` is already stated as a foreign key in Posts Model.

**A running version of the DEMO API is here:**

https://thymesis-memories.herokuapp.com/api/memories/create

```
django-version: 2.1.3
DRS-version: 3.9.0
```

Comment: Where is your view code?

Comment: Let me add it shortly @RedCricket

Comment: `user_id = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` This attribute will be a `User` object, I guess it's better to rename it to `user` only. Posts().user_id will give Users(). 
And why model name is plural ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the Post Creation like this:

```
a_Post = Posts.objects.create(
        user_id_id = request.data['user_id'],  # <-- Here
        title=request.data["title"],
        location=request.data["location"],
        summary=request.data["summary"],
        post_body=request.data["post_body"],
        uri=request.data["uri"],
        votes=request.data["votes"]

    )
```

Use **user** instead of **user_id** because its a ForeignKey field and when you use `user = ForeignKey(User)` then you can access user id at `post.user_id`. Also django creates the the table column named `user_id` if you define the FK as `user`.

Comment: I have tried your code but got the following error:

foreign key mismatch - "memories_posts" referencing "memories_users" 


PS: memories is the project name.. root folder

Comment: are you sure? Because in the updated answer I havn't defined any User object.

Comment: I have tried the objects.get(pk) method and got the below error:

["'Users object (528c2d9e-da2e-4c3d-9a92-eafb98e5d06e)' is not a valid UUID."]

maybe it is a problem with the UUID? maybe changing it to Interger might fix the problem.

Comment: it worked now.. I have changed the model as you have suggested then it worked.